# Minimum number of directed edges for a cycle of length $L$ to necessarily exist

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, ramsey-theory

Given a directed graph with *V* vertices, what is the minimum number of (directed) edges (no self-loops) for a cycle of length *L* to ***necessarily*** exist.

I can show that we can add 1 directed edge for every pair of vertex without creating a cycle (it becomes a directed acyclic graph). It is easy to argue that, after this exercise, the next directed edge will create a loop. Therefore :

> $\frac{V(V-1)}{2}+1$  directed edges in a graph imply existence of *some* cycle.

How do I move ahead from here?

Edit: I am assuming that at most 1 directed edge can exist between any two vertices.

Answer (score 1):

Let $V(D) = \{v_1, \dots, v_{k(L-1)+j}\}$, where $k$ is a non-negative integer, and $j\in \{0,1,\dots, L-2\}$. Building upon what you already know, we might as well add all arcs in one direction; this will not create a cycle, say all arcs of the form $(v_a,v_b)$ for $a<b$. Our idea now will be to add as many arcs as possible without creating a cycle of length $L$.

Let us partition $V(D)$ into $k$ sets of size $L-1$, and a set of size $j$, say $V_i = \{v_{1+(i-1)(L-1)}, \dots, v_{i(L-1)}\}$ for $i\in \{1, \dots, k\}$ and $V_{k+1}$ the last $j$ vertices. Observe that we can put all the arcs in the reverse order in each $V_i$ without creating a cycle of length $L$, as any cycle created is contained in a set $V_i$, and $|V_i|\leq L-1$. Thus, every $V_i$ is complete digraph, and it follows that adding any arc at this point creates a cycle of length $L$ (and potentially some longer cycles too, depending on with arc we add).

The above argument shows there are digraphs with no cycle of length $L$ and at least $\binom{k(l-1)+j}{2}+k\binom{l-1}{2}+\binom{j}{2}$ arcs. To show that we cannot have any arcs more is some more work, but I believe it to be true.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you allow multiple edges between your vertices. If you also allow them to have the same direction, your argumentation does not seem to be correct. The last edge you add can have the same direction as the previous edge connecting the same vertices. In this case, if you want to prove the existence of cycles, you might need more conditions for the graph you are constructing.
For a contradiction, you can imagine an acyclic triangle with multiple edges and the same direction between any two vertices. If you connect each new vertex with edges going towards each point of the previous graph, you will construct a larger graph without cycles. You can ad as many edges as you want but if they repeat the direction of the previous edges, you will not have a cycle.

Comment: This is really a comment and not an answer.